# Using an array function inside a prompt

Tags: javascript, arrays, prompt

I am doing a project for a class in which I have to have a user input names, and then have the program alphabetically sort the names. The code that I've come up with isn't very elegant, but it works fine to get the user to input 3 different names and then print the names on the screen.  However, I cannot figure out how to sort the names. Am I able to put an array inside the disp_prompt() function?  I tried doing this and it didnt' seem to work, although I may be putting the array code in the wrong area.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
<body>

<script> 

function disp_prompt() 
  {
  var name1=prompt("Please enter three names:","Name 1")
  var name2=prompt("Please enter three names:","Name 2")
  var name3=prompt("Please enter three names:","Name 3")
  document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML= name1;
  document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML= name2;
  document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML= name3;
  }

</script> 

<center><input type="button" onclick="disp_prompt()" value="Click Here"></center>
<br>

<h2><center><div id="msg1"></div></center></h2>
<h2><center><div id="msg2"></div></center></h2>
<h2><center><div id="msg3"></div></center></h2>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the user's input in an array and use a for loop:

```
var theArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var plusOne = i + 1;
    theArray[i] = prompt("Please enter threee names: ", "Name " + plusOne);
    document.getElementById("msg" + plusOne).innerHTML = theArray[i];
}
```

Once your names are in an array, it will be trivial to sort them:

`theArray.sort();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma-separated input:

```
function dispComment() {
    var names, input;
    input = prompt("Please enter three names (comma separated):","Name1,Name2,Name3");
    names = input.split(',');
    // Check names length if it is needed
    names.sort();
    // In the end, you'll have a sorted names array, assign to the fields
    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML= names[0];
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML= names[1];
    document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML= names[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create an array.
2. Then populate it.
3. Then use array indexing to populate the html.

Like so:

```
...
var namesArray = [name1,name2,name3].sort();
document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML= namesArray[0];
document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML= namesArray[1];
document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML= namesArray[2];
```